react dnd drag cancelled
my drag and drop functionality gets cancelled when I drop widget and it comes back to its  original position
i am working on dashboard component that consist of many card like widgets , i want to add drag and drop functionality on these cards. I have used react beautiful dnd (DragDropContext>Droppable>Draggable)
but I am facing an issue and unable to solve, when I drag a widget and drop it on new location it comes back to its original position. I have logged the drag result and this what I got:
Drag Result:
{draggableId: 'apps', type: 'DEFAULT', source: {…}, reason: 'CANCEL', mode: 'FLUID', …}
combine
:
null
destination
:
null
draggableId
:
"apps"
mode
:
"FLUID"
reason
:
"CANCEL"
source
:
{index: 26, droppableId: 'dashboard-widgets'}
type
:
"DEFAULT"
below is my code for dashboard component:
import { css } from "@emotion/css";
import { Button, Col, Layout, Popover, Row, Tree, Typography } from "antd";
import React, { Suspense, lazy, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { addDashboardWidgetAction } from "../../../store/action/admin/dashbaordWidgetAction";
import DashboardLayoutDrawer from "./DashboardLayoutDrawer";
import {
  allWidgets,
  defaultTemplate,
  widgetsAvailable,
} from "./widgetArrayData";
import ContactSupport from "./ContactSupport";
import Element4Icon from "../../../Theme/CustomIcons/Icons/Grid/Element4Icon";
import { TranslatorDashboardTag } from "../../../languageTranslator/LanguageTranslatorTags";
import { DragDropContext, Draggable, Droppable } from "react-beautiful-dnd";
import { MdDragHandle } from "react-icons/md";
const { Title, Text } = Typography;
// Activity Overview
const TeamsCard = lazy(() => import("./FirstColCards/teamsCard"));

//open postion
const OpenHiring = lazy(() => import("./recruitmentWidgets/openHiring"));

// Total Applications
const TotalApplication = lazy(() =>
  import("./recruitmentWidgets/totalApplication")
);

// Recent Positions
const RecentPosition = lazy(() =>
  import("./recruitmentWidgets/recentPosition")
);
const JobSummary = lazy(() => import("./recruitmentWidgets/jobSummary"));

// WHAT'S HAPPENING
const HappeningCard = lazy(() => import("./ForColCards/happeningCard"));

//ORGANIZATION HEADCOUNT
const OrganizationWidget = lazy(() => import("./HrmsWidgets/orgWidget"));

// Recent Announcements
const AnnouncementWidget = lazy(() =>
  import("./HrmsWidgets/announcementWidget")
);
const ProdCard = lazy(() => import("./SecColCards/prodCard"));
const ProjectCard = lazy(() => import("./SecColCards/projectCard"));
const ScreenLog = lazy(() => import("./ThirdColCards/screenLog"));
const LeavesWidget = lazy(() => import("./HrmsWidgets/leavesWidget"));
const CalendarWidget = lazy(() => import("./HrmsWidgets/calendarWidget"));
const AppLogsCard = lazy(() => import("./FirstColCards/appLogsCard"));
const BirthdayWidget = lazy(() => import("./HrmsWidgets/birthdayWidget"));
const WorkAnniversaryWidget = lazy(() =>
  import("./HrmsWidgets/workAnniversaryWidget")
);
const CheckinGraphCard = lazy(() =>
  import("./SecColCards/hrmGraph/checkinGraphCard")
);
const DocExpiryCard = lazy(() => import("./HrmsWidgets/docExpiryCard"));
const NationalityChartCard = lazy(() =>
  import("./HrmsWidgets/nationalityChartCard")
);
const GenderChartCard = lazy(() => import("./HrmsWidgets/genderChartCard"));
const AgeChartCard = lazy(() => import("./HrmsWidgets/ageChartCard"));
const LeaderBoardCard = lazy(() => import("./ForColCards/leaderBoardCard"));
const TodaysLogCard = lazy(() => import("./ThirdColCards/todaysLogCard"));
const OnboardingTasksWidget = lazy(() =>
  import("./FirstColCards/onboardingTasksWidget")
);
const CompanyResourcesWidget = lazy(() =>
  import("./HrmsWidgets/CompanyResourcesWidget")
);

const { Content } = Layout;
const SuspenseLoader = ({ children }) => (
  <Suspense
    fallback={
      <div
        style={{
          height: "100vh",
          display: "flex",
          justifyContent: "center",
          alignItems: "center",
        }}
      >
        <img src="/Loader1.gif" height="60%" />
      </div>
    }
  >
    {children}
  </Suspense>
);
function DashboardAdminContent() {
  const [widgets, setWidgets] = useState([]);
  const [mergedArray, setMergedArray] = useState([]);
  const [openKeys, setopenKeys] = useState([]);
  const [timeout1, setTimeout1] = useState(null);
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [newarrays, setNewarrays] = useState([]);
  const themeDefault = useSelector((state) => state.themeDefault);
  const sharedUserInfo = useSelector(
    (state) => state.sharedLogin.sharedUserInfo
  );
  const getDashboardWidgetList = useSelector(
    (state) => state.getDashboardWidgetList
  );
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  let userType = "";
  if (sharedUserInfo?.payload) {
    userType = sharedUserInfo?.payload?.type;
  } else {
    userType = sharedUserInfo?.type;
  }
  const roleFeatures = sharedUserInfo.userAccess;

  let industry;
  if (sharedUserInfo?.payload?.company) {
    industry = sharedUserInfo?.payload?.company?.modules;
  } else {
    industry = sharedUserInfo?.empCompanies[0]?.companyId?.modules;
  }
  const WIDGET_COMPONENTS = {
    teams: TeamsCard,
    // openHiring: OpenHiring,
    // totalApplication: TotalApplication,

    recentPosition: RecentPosition,
    jobSummary: JobSummary,
    happening: HappeningCard,
    OrganizationWidget: OrganizationWidget,
    announcement: AnnouncementWidget,
    productivity: ProdCard,
    project: ProjectCard,
    screen: ScreenLog,
    leaves:
      (userType === "admin" ||
        (userType !== "user" &&
          (roleFeatures?.includes("19") ||
            roleFeatures?.includes("20") ||
            roleFeatures?.includes("21")))) &&
      LeavesWidget,
    calendar: CalendarWidget,
    apps: AppLogsCard,
    birthday: BirthdayWidget,
    workAnniversary: WorkAnniversaryWidget,
    checkinGraph: CheckinGraphCard,
    documentexpiry: DocExpiryCard,
    nationalityChart: NationalityChartCard,
    genderChart: GenderChartCard,
    ageChart: AgeChartCard,
    leaderBoardCard:
      userType !== "admin" && userType !== "user" && LeaderBoardCard,
    // todaysLogCard: TodaysLogCard,
    onboardingTasks: OnboardingTasksWidget,
    companyResources: CompanyResourcesWidget,
  };
  const onCheck = (checkedKeysValue) => {
    setWidgets(checkedKeysValue);
    console.log({
      h: getDashboardWidgetList?.getDashboardWidgetInfo?.widgetListTemp,
    });
    const delay = 3000;

    if (timeout1) {
      clearTimeout(timeout1);
    }
    const time = setTimeout(async () => {
      try {
        if (
          getDashboardWidgetList?.getDashboardWidgetInfo &&
          getDashboardWidgetList?.getDashboardWidgetInfo?.widgetListTemp &&
          getDashboardWidgetList?.getDashboardWidgetInfo?.widgetListTemp
            .length > 0
        ) {
          const savedLayout = [];
          newarrays.forEach((columnData, columnIndex) => {
            Object.values(columnData).forEach((items) => {
              items.forEach((item, index) => {
                if (checkedKeysValue.includes(item.i)) {
                  return savedLayout.push({
                    title: item?.i,
                    position: {
                      w: item?.w,
                      h: item?.h,
                      x: columnIndex,
                      y: index,
                      i: item?.i,
                      moved: item?.moved,
                      static: item?.static,
                      isDraggable: true,
                      isResizable: false,
                    },
                  });
                }
              });
            });
          });
          defaultTemplate.forEach((columnData, columnIndex) => {
            Object.values(columnData).forEach((items) => {
              items.forEach((item, index) => {
                if (
                  checkedKeysValue.includes(item.i) &&
                  !savedLayout.find((e) => e.position?.i === item?.i)
                ) {
                  return savedLayout.push({
                    title: item?.i,
                    position: {
                      w: item?.w,
                      h: item?.h,
                      x: columnIndex,
                      y: index,
                      i: item?.i,
                      moved: item?.moved,
                      static: item?.static,
                      isDraggable: true,
                      isResizable: false,
                    },
                  });
                }
              });
            });
          });

          const data = {
            widgetListTemp: savedLayout,
          };

          await dispatch(addDashboardWidgetAction(data));
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }, delay);
    setTimeout1(time);
  };
  const organizeByX = (originalArray) => {
    const organizedArray = [];

    const xValues = originalArray.reduce((acc, item) => {
      if (!acc[item.x]) {
        acc[item.x] = [];
      }
      acc[item.x].push(item);
      return acc;
    }, {});

    for (const x in xValues) {
      const newObj = {};
      newObj[`x${x}`] = xValues[x].map(({ w, h, y, i }) => ({ w, h, y, i }));
      organizedArray.push(newObj);
    }

    return organizedArray;
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    let openWidgets = [];
    let availableWidgets = [];

    allWidgets &&
      allWidgets.length > 0 &&
      allWidgets.map((a) => {
        const showWidget = industry?.find((d) => a?.openWidget === d);
        if (showWidget && a.show(userType, roleFeatures)) {
          openWidgets.push(a?.widget);
        }
      });
    widgetsAvailable &&
      widgetsAvailable.length > 0 &&
      widgetsAvailable.map((a) => {
        const showWidgets = industry?.find((d) => a?.openWidget === d);
        if (showWidgets && a.show(userType, roleFeatures)) {
          availableWidgets.push({ key: a?.key, title: a?.title });
        }
      });
    setWidgets(openWidgets);
    setopenKeys(availableWidgets);
  }, [industry]);
  useEffect(() => {
    let openWidgets = [];
    if (
      getDashboardWidgetList &&
      getDashboardWidgetList?.getDashboardWidgetInfo &&
      getDashboardWidgetList?.getDashboardWidgetInfo?.widgetListTemp &&
      getDashboardWidgetList?.getDashboardWidgetInfo?.widgetListTemp.length > 0
    ) {
      const widgets =
        getDashboardWidgetList?.getDashboardWidgetInfo?.widgetListTemp
          ?.sort((a, b) => a.y - b.y)
          ?.map((data) => data?.position?.i)
          ?.filter(Boolean);
      widgets.map((a) => {
        if (allWidgets && allWidgets.length > 0) {
          const showWidget = allWidgets?.find((d) => a === d?.widget);
          if (showWidget) {
            openWidgets.push(a);
          }
        }
      });
      setWidgets(openWidgets);
    }
  }, [getDashboardWidgetList?.getDashboardWidgetInfo]);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (
      getDashboardWidgetList?.getDashboardWidgetInfo &&
      getDashboardWidgetList?.getDashboardWidgetInfo?.widgetListTemp &&
      getDashboardWidgetList?.getDashboardWidgetInfo?.widgetListTemp.length > 0
    ) {
      const savedLayout = [];
      defaultTemplate.forEach((columnData, columnIndex) => {
        Object.values(columnData).forEach((items) => {
          items.forEach((item, index) => {
            if (widgets.includes(item.i)) {
              return savedLayout.push({
                title: item?.i,
                position: {
                  w: item?.w,
                  h: item?.h,
                  x: columnIndex,
                  y: index,
                  i: item?.i,
                  moved: item?.moved,
                  static: item?.static,
                  isDraggable: true,
                  isResizable: false,
                },
              });
            }
          });
        });
      });

      const mergedArray = [...savedLayout];

      getDashboardWidgetList?.getDashboardWidgetInfo?.widgetListTemp.forEach(
        () => {}
      );

      const tempArray = [];

      getDashboardWidgetList?.getDashboardWidgetInfo?.widgetListTemp
        .sort((a, b) => a.y - b.y)
        .map((data) => {
          if (widgets.includes(data?.title)) {
            tempArray.push({
              w: data?.position?.w,
              h: data?.position?.h,
              x: data?.position?.x,
              y: data?.position?.y,
              i: data?.position?.i,
              minH: data?.position?.h,
              isResizable: false,
              isDraggable: true,
            });
          }
        });
      mergedArray
        .sort((a, b) => a.y - b.y)
        .map((data) => {
          if (
            widgets.includes(data?.title) &&
            !tempArray.find((e) => e.i === data?.position?.i)
          ) {
            tempArray.push({
              w: data?.position?.w,
              h: data?.position?.h,
              x: data?.position?.x,
              y: data?.position?.y,
              i: data?.position?.i,
              minH: data?.position?.h,
              isResizable: false,
              isDraggable: true,
            });
          }
        })
        .filter(Boolean);
      const newArray = organizeByX(tempArray);
      setNewarrays(newArray);
    } else {
      setNewarrays(defaultTemplate);
    }
  }, [getDashboardWidgetList?.getDashboardWidgetInfo, widgets]);

  const handleDragEnd = (result) => {
    console.log("Drag Result:", result);
    if (!result.destination) {
      console.log("Dropped outside the droppable area");
      return;
    } // Exit if dropped outside

    const { source, destination } = result;
    console.log("Source index:", source.index);
    console.log("Destination index:", destination.index);

    const updatedArray = Array.from(newarrays); // Clone your array

    // Extract the column from the source and destination
    const sourceColumn = updatedArray[source.droppableId];
    const destinationColumn = updatedArray[destination.droppableId];

    // Get the item from the source column and remove it
    const [movedItem] = sourceColumn.splice(source.index, 1);

    // Insert the item into the destination column
    destinationColumn.splice(destination.index, 0, movedItem);

    // Update state with new array
    setNewarrays(updatedArray);
    console.log("Updated widgets order:", updatedArray);
  };

  let globalIndex = 0;
  return (
    <DragDropContext onDragEnd={handleDragEnd}>
      <SuspenseLoader>
        {getDashboardWidgetList?.loadings ? (
          <div
            style={{
              height: "100vh",
              display: "flex",
              justifyContent: "center",
              alignItems: "center",
            }}
          >
            <img src="/Loader1.gif" height="60%" />
          </div>
        ) : (
          <Row>
            <Col
              span={24}
              style={{
                margin: "15px 0px",
                marginTop: " 30px",
              }}
            >
              <Content>
                <Row style={{ display: "flex", alignItems: "center" }}>
                  <Col
                    span={12}
                    className={css`
                      .ant-typography {
                        font-size: ${themeDefault?.info?.newConfig
                          ?.titleSecondaryFontSize};
                      }
                    `}
                  >
                    {sharedUserInfo?.payload?.name?.firstName && (
                      <Title level={4}>
                        <TranslatorDashboardTag>Hello</TranslatorDashboardTag>{" "}
                        {sharedUserInfo?.payload?.name?.firstName} 
                      </Title>
                    )}
                  </Col>
                  <Col span={12} align="right">
                    <div
                      className={css`
                        .ant-popover-title {
                          border-bottom: 1px solid #f3f3f3 !important;
                          display: block !important;
                        }
                      `}
                      style={{
                        display: "flex",
                        justifyContent: "flex-end",
                        gap: "10px",
                      }}
                    >
                      <Popover
                        placement="bottomRight"
                        content={
                          <Row
                            style={{
                              display: "flex",
                              padding: "20px",
                              width: "240px",
                            }}
                          >
                            <Col
                              span={24}
                              style={{
                                marginBottom: "10px",
                                display: "flex",
                                width: "100%",
                                justifyContent: "space-between",
                                alignItems: "center",
                              }}
                            >
                              <Text>
                                <TranslatorDashboardTag>
                                  Widgets
                                </TranslatorDashboardTag>
                              </Text>
                              <DashboardLayoutDrawer
                                mergedArray={newarrays}
                                data={newarrays}
                                widgets={widgets}
                              />
                            </Col>
                            <Col
                              span={24}
                              className={css`
                                :where(
                                    .css-dev-only-do-not-override-1v9rcfr
                                  ).ant-tree
                                  .ant-tree-switcher {
                                  width: 0px !important;
                                }
                                .ant-tree
                                  .ant-tree-treenode
                                  .ant-tree-switcher-noop {
                                  display: none !important;
                                }
                                .ant-tree .ant-tree-node-content-wrapper,
                                .ant-tree .ant-tree-checkbox + span {
                                  cursor: auto;
                                }
                                .ant-tree .ant-tree-node-content-wrapper,
                                .ant-tree .ant-tree-checkbox + span:hover {
                                  background: none;
                                }
                                .ant-tree
                                  .ant-tree-node-content-wrapper.ant-tree-node-selected,
                                .ant-tree
                                  .ant-tree-checkbox
                                  + span.ant-tree-node-selected {
                                  background: none !important;
                                }
                                .ant-tree
                                  .ant-tree-node-content-wrapper.ant-tree-node-selected,
                                .ant-tree
                                  .ant-tree-checkbox
                                  + span.ant-tree-node-selected:focus {
                                  background: none !important;
                                }
                              `}
                            >
                              <Tree
                                checkable
                                treeData={openKeys}
                                onCheck={onCheck}
                                defaultCheckedKeys={widgets}
                              />
                            </Col>
                          </Row>
                        }
                        trigger="click"
                      >
                        <Text
                          style={{
                            display: "flex",
                            alignItems: "center",
                            justifyContent: "center",
                            gap: "5px",
                            cursor: "pointer",
                          }}
                        >
                          <TranslatorDashboardTag>
                            Manage Widgets
                          </TranslatorDashboardTag>
                          <Element4Icon size={"small"} />
                        </Text>
                      </Popover>

                      {}
                    </div>
                  </Col>
                </Row>
              </Content>
            </Col>
            <Col span={24}>
              <Content>
                {true ? (
                  <Droppable droppableId="dashboard-widgets">
                    {(provided) => (
                      <Row
                        gutter={[16, 16]}
                        {...provided.droppableProps}
                        ref={provided.innerRef}
                      >
                        {newarrays.map((columnData, columnIndex) => (
                          <Col
                            span={8}
                            xs={24}
                            sm={24}
                            md={12}
                            lg={12}
                            xl={8}
                            xxl={8}
                            key={`column-${columnIndex}`}
                          >
                            {Object.values(columnData).map((items) => {
                              return items.map((item) => {
                                if (
                                  WIDGET_COMPONENTS[item.i] &&
                                  widgets.includes(item.i)
                                ) {
                                  console.log("globalIndex:", globalIndex);
                                  // Use globalIndex to ensure unique and consecutive index across all columns
                                  return (
                                    <Draggable
                                      key={item.i}
                                      draggableId={item.i}
                                      index={globalIndex++}
                                    >
                                      {(provided) => (
                                        <div
                                          ref={provided.innerRef}
                                          {...provided.draggableProps}
                                          {...provided.dragHandleProps}
                                          style={{
                                            marginBottom: "20px",
                                            ...provided.draggableProps.style,
                                          }}
                                        >
                                          {React.createElement(
                                            WIDGET_COMPONENTS[item.i]
                                          )}
                                        </div>
                                      )}
                                    </Draggable>
                                  );
                                }
                              });
                            })}
                          </Col>
                        ))}
                        {provided.placeholder}
                      </Row>
                    )}
                  </Droppable>
                ) : (
                  <></>
                )}
              </Content>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        )}
      </SuspenseLoader>
    </DragDropContext>
  );
}
export default React.memo(DashboardAdminContent);


